# Не меняется значение value в input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть данный код, не могу заставить изменяться поля для ввода, при вводе данный ничего не происходит.

```
export default function Crossword9x9() {

  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({ input: '' });

  function onChangeHandler(e) {
    setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const GetInputFields = (props) => {
    let fields = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < props.countFields; i++) {
      fields.push(
        <InputCase key={'input' + i} name={'input' + i} />
      );
    }
    return (fields);
  }

  return (
    <form className="app" onChange={onChangeHandler}>

      <GetInputFields countFields={10} />

    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Событие "onChange" должно быть у элементов input и value тоже, в которое будете присваивать стэйт.

Comment: просто я думал при помощи делегирования событий избавиться от прописывания каждому элементу)

Comment: Не сталкивался с делигированием. Но если и правда ваш хэндлер реагирует на изменение в инпутах, то вам необходимо указать defaultValue ваш стейт конкретного инпута.  Что-то типа такого: (Не тестил)

`<InputCase key={'input' + i} name={'input' + i} defaultValue={inputValues['input' + i]}/>`